# Type Error : Object(...) is not a function at Module.../../../../../../../../../../../SecondAtt/RealNavigation/Routing/Navigator.js

Tags: react-native

I have a type error in my react-navigation while using createAppContainer

```
import { createStackNavigator , createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';

 const RootStack = createStackNavigator(
     {
        Form : Form ,
        ListView : ListView,
     },
     {
         initialRouteName : Form,
     },
);

const AppNavigating = createAppContainer(RootStack);
```

> Object(...) is not a function
>       at Module.../../../../../../../../../../../SecondAtt/RealNavigation/Routing/Navigator.js
>   (Navigator.js:15)

Comment: `initialRouteName` takes string value and you are not passing string try `initialRouteName : 'Form'`

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is here,

```
{
  initialRouteName : Form,
}
```

`initialRouteName` takes `string` and you are not passing `string`, do this,

```
{
  initialRouteName : 'Form',
}
```